# export file php to xls uses class PHPExcel

Tags: php

I want to export some file php to XLS file use class PHPEXcel, I don't used this before.

notif on my browser: 
**"Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 25165824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 1056 bytes) in C:\AppServ\www\kjjp2\Classes\PHPExcel\Cell.php on line 1124"**

code:

```
    <?php
    include "config/koneksi.php";

    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    require_once 'Classes/PHPExcel.php';
    // Create new PHPExcel object
    $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

    $query = "SELECT * FROM `tabeldata`";
    $hasil = mysql_query($query);

    // Set properties
    $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator("Erik")
    ->setLastModifiedBy("Erik")
    ->setTitle("Office 2007 XLSX ")
    ->setSubject("Office 2007 XLSX ")
    ->setDescription("Document for Office 2007 XLSX, generated using PHP classes.")
    ->setKeywords("office 2007 openxml php")
   ->setCategory("Test result file");

    // Add some data
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
    ->setCellValue('A1', 'Jenis Report')
    ->setCellValue('B1', 'Pembayaran')
    ->setCellValue('C1', 'No')
    ->setCellValue('D1', 'Cabang')
     //and some files


    ->setCellValue('AG1', 'Surveyor');

    $rowNya = 3;
    $no = 0;
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($hasil)){
    $no = $no +1;
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)

    ->setCellValue("A$rowNya", $row['jenReport'])
    ->setCellValue("B$rowNya", $row['pembayaran'])
     ->setCellValue("C$rowNya", $row['no'])
     ->setCellValue("D$rowNya", $row['cabang'])
    ->setCellValue("E$rowNya", $row['namaSales'])
    ->setCellValue("F$rowNya", $row['jenLaporan'])
          //and some files

    ->setCellValue("AG$rowNya", $row['surveyor']);


    $rowNya = $rowNya + 1;
    }

    // Rename sheet
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Simple');

    // Set active sheet index to the first sheet, so Excel opens this as the first sheet
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

    // Redirect output to a client’s web browser (Excel5)
    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="database.xls"');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
    $objWriter->save('php://output');
    exit;
    ?>
```

Comment: Thank you Gowry. Sorry my english is not good :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are running out of RAM that can be used by PHP. You can set how much RAM that PHP will use in php.ini. You currently have this limit set to 24MB, which is pretty low. Try increasing it.

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '256M');
```

Comment: dontomaso.
I've set memory limit like your suggest, but not solved. I still have same problem.

Comment: Dontomaso.
Sorry, i was wrong to set memory limit on php.ini.
After i do it rigth, my problem solved.
Thank you so much.

Comment: I've some file php and want to export to XLS file. I can do it with my code. But, i've problem, i want to export not all file, but i want to export file that i've selected with sort.
Can you help me plis?

Comment: Please post that as a separate question instead of as a comment, possibly referring to this one.

Answer (score 0):

PHPExcel is known for being memory hungry. The website has a discussions with some workarounds, see http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/discussions/242712?ProjectName=phpexcel

You could also consider using another library like the old Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer lib (which has its drawbacks as well)
http://pear.php.net/package/Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer/redirected